# How to Allow ^ character in URLs for tomcat 8.5

Tags: tomcat8

I have a request URL of below format

```
http://hostname:port/path&param1={"vars":[{"a":"val1","b":"^"},{"c":"val2","d":"^"}]}&param2=Value3|95|3%20-%206%20Months
```

I changed catalina.properties as per this
[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220740/why-is-this-url-returning-error-400-from-tomcat?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) .

But as per [tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html) **tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow** property is deprecated and **relaxedPathChars** and **relaxedQueryChars** attributes are to be used with Connector tag instead.

However, when i change the xml file to below

```
 <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" relaxedQueryChars="^" relaxedPathChars="^"/>
```

I still get a 400 bad request for the character **^**

I am not sure if this is the correct configuration.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Ideally you should always URL-encode your query parameters before sending your request to the server. Read: [https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/misc/lunatech%5Ewhat-every-webdev-must-know-about-url-encoding/](https://www.talisman.org/%7Eerlkonig/misc/lunatech%5Ewhat-every-webdev-must-know-about-url-encoding/)

If you want to go down the relaxedQueryChars route, note that the following chars from your query are also in the set that you ought to add to the exception:
`" { } [ ] ^ |`

Try this in your server.xml:

`<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" relaxedQueryChars='^{}[]|&quot;' />`

More insight into relaxedQueryChars/relaxedPathChars on the [bug ticket 62273](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62273). The change was added to all branches of Tomat:

- 9.0.8
- 8.5.31
- 8.0.52
- 7.0.87

I don't think you need the relaxedPathChars attribute at all (this refers to characters on the URL path).  However, [the Tomcat team's test results](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Encoding+and+URIs) seem to suggest that the following could be used for maximum backward-compatibility:

`relaxedPathChars='[]|' relaxedQueryChars='[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;'`

*nb/ the first arg to your query should be demarcated by ? not &*

`http://hostname:port/path?param1=...&param2=...&param3=...`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had figured it out though that the relaxedQueryChars is supported in tomcat 8.5.31 in 8.5.x line.

Answer (score 7):

It is required to use unicode instead of the literal `<` or `>` characters. Here is the actual `relaxedQueryChars` value I have in `server.xml`:

```
relaxedQueryChars="&#x5B;&#x5D;&#x7C;&#x7B;&#x7D;&#x5E;&#x5C;&#x60;&#x22;&#x3C;&#x3E;"
&#x5B; -> [
&#x5D; -> ]
&#x7C; -> |
&#x7B; -> {
&#x7D; -> }
&#x5E; -> ^
&#x5C; -> \
&#x60; -> `
&#x22; -> "
&#x3C; -> <
&#x3E; -> >
```

Comment: this will work only if the server.xml is being edited by hand. Any attempt to read & write this file will corrupt the file.