# We are using java 8 with Tomcat version 7.0.84, we get 400 error for invalid characters

Tags: java, tomcat7

We are getting 400 error when url has invalid chars eg.

we tried to update the server.xml with below property, we still get the same error
relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^\`"<>"

can someone please help on the issue.

Comment: e.g. ?!php/object+"O:24:"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\FnStream":2:

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361171/how-to-allow-character-in-urls-for-tomcat-8-5 could be useful

Comment: Exactly how have you configured server.xml to use relaxedQueryChars?

Comment: @MarkThomas I have tried the following <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               relaxedPathChars='^{}|[\]'
               relaxedQueryChars="^{}|[\]"
               />